# NXT Sensors/Motors not working

Tags: mindstorms, nxt, repair, sensor

I went back to using the NXT brick after two years and I'm having some problems:

- Motors do not respond to degrees or rotations;
- Ultrasonic Sensor and Color Sensor are not working;
- Touch Sensor is ok;

My Firmware version is V1.31. What can it be?

Comment: Do you have enough parts to cross-check the non-functioning items with other hubs? That way you could narrow down the problem scope - as of now, it can be in the NXT hub internal hardware, the firmware, your software, the port on the NXT side, the cable connector, the cable itself or the end device (sensor/motor).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I changed the capacitor C61 and everything worked again.

Comment: If you'd write an answer detailing how you managed to find and fix the problem I'd definitely upvote it. If you could add photos to help others with the same problem, I could add a bounty as well.